# Find ArrayList method to Find Array method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I made a method which finds a value in my ArrayList. I also copied this method so I could use it for my array but certain things such as the get and size don't work. I'm unsure how I'm supposed to restructure it.

```
public Product findProduct(String givenProduct) throws IllegalProductCodeException {
            IllegalProductCodeException notFoundMessage
                    = new IllegalProductCodeException("Product was not found");
            int size = rangeOfProducts.length;
            int i = 0;
            boolean productFound = false;
            while (!productFound && i < size) {         //While book hasn't been found and i is less than the size of the array
                productFound = rangeOfProducts.get(i).getProductCode().equals(givenProduct);
                //Checks whether the given value in the array's reference is equal to the given reference entered
                i++; //if not then add 1
            }
            if (productFound) {
                return rangeOfProducts.get(i - 1);
            } else {
                throw notFoundMessage;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array alternative to `.get(i)` will be `[i]` and the alternative to `.size()` will be `.length`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Product product : products) {
  if (product.getProductCode().equals(givenProduct)) {
    return product;
  }
}
throw new IllegalProductCodeException("Product was not found");
```

**Edit**: Java 5's enhanced for loop is equivalent to

```
for (Iterator<Product> iter=products.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
  Product product = iter.next();
```

Comment: Can you speak me through your answer please? It looks very efficient but don't quite understand it

Comment: @user3667111 : This is a foreach loop structure introduced in Java 5 that will automagically loop through an entire array (or Collection, or anything else that implements Iterable) for you. If you've never used it before, you're gonna **love** it.  More info at https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with.  If one of the iterations through the loop finds the matching element, it returns it (thus immediately breaking out of the loop).  If it reaches the end of the list (meaning that it didn't find a match), it throws the exception instead.